# PEP 8: comparison to True should be 'if cond is True:' or 'if cond:'

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm is throwing a warning when I do np.where(temp == True)

My full code:

```
from numpy import where, array

a = array([[0.4682], [0.5318]])
b = array([[0.29828851, 0., 0.28676873, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.28801431, 0., 0., 0.71283046, 0.],
          [0.70171149, 0., 0.71323127, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.71198569, 0., 0., 0.28716954, 0.]])

temp = b > 1.1*a
pos = where(temp == True)

print(pos)
```

The code does not work as expected if I change temp == True to temp is True as suggested in other post.

How should this warning be resolved?

where(temp) works. Thanks a lot !! @Joao Vitorino 
Thanks for the explanation, @jedwards. It helps.

Comment: pos = where(temp)

Comment: Also, you should understand the difference between `x == True` and `x is True`.  The former will evaluate to True if x is True-like (equivalent to `bool(x) == True` -- so `1 == True`, `"String" == True`, etc will all pass this test.  The latter using `is` tests for reference equality and will match only *exactly* the boolean True.

Comment: if `temp` is a boolean, or that function takes a boolean, just do `np.where(temp)`

Comment: FWIW, I like it when code looks like a proper English sentence, so `if cond is True` is nicer in this aspect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't compare boolean against boolean.

You should check if is True or false.

```
b == true
if b: # If b is True
   do something
```

In your case

```
temp = b > 1.1*a
pos = where(temp)
```

[Here](https://faisalferoz.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/why-boolean-true-type-of-comparisions-should-be-avoided/) some explanations

Answer (score 0):

As per the PEP8 Guidelines in Python, comparing things to True is not a preferred pattern.

```
temp = True
pcos = where(temp)
```

If the 'temp' is assigned to be false, still specifying only 'temp' inside a conditional statement will result True. For instance:

```
temp = False
pros = while(temp) # if or while condition
```

NOTE: If your code doesn't follow PEP8, this case will not give any error.