# How can I append a Boolean value to a text file?

Tags: python, boolean, text-files, shopify, monitoring

I'm trying to add a boolean value to a text file but get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valentinwestermann/Documents/La dieta mediterranea_dhooks.py", line 32, in <module>
    f.write(variant["available"])
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bool
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? : )
It is supposed to work as a restock monitor and make a text version of the product availability when the bot launches and then constantly compare it and notifiers the user about product restocks.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dhooks import Webhook
import requests
import json

r = requests.get("https://www.feature.com/products.json")
products = json.loads((r.text))["products"]

for product in products:
    print("============================================")
    print(product["title"])
    print(product["tags"])
    print(product["published_at"])
    print(product["created_at"])
    print(product["product_type"])
    for variant in product["variants"]:
        print(variant['title'])
        print(variant['available'],"\n")

        data =("available")
with open("stock_index.txt","w") as f:
    for product in products:        
        for variant in product["variants"]:
            if variant['available'] == True:
                f.write(product["title"])
                f.write(variant['title'])
                print(variant["available"])
                f.write("--------------------")
```

Comment: Your error message says that there's an error involving `f.write(variant["available"])` but your code does not contain any instruction like that. Also please don't use `if variant['available'] == True` to test if a boolean is true or false. A simple `if variant['available']:` will suffice

Comment: Thank you : ) It is better, as it uses less code, right? @Sorix

Comment: this is the recommended way to test booleans. Have a look at this question and the validated answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816182/pep-8-comparison-to-true-should-be-if-cond-is-true-or-if-cond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to a string first:

```
f.write(str(variant["available"]))
```